# cargo generate using ssh results in: Git Error: Failed to authenticate SSH session: ; class=Ssh (23)

Tags: ssh, rust-cargo

I'm currently struggling getting cargo-generate to work properly with ssh.
Generating from github using https works fine.
I have no issues using git by itselve as well, but for some obscure reason cargo generate does not play nicely with it.
Here is the error I am presented with, after trying to clone a simple template of mine:

```bash
cargo generate git@github.com:VirtualNonsense/rust_bluepill_minimal_template.git
 Using application config: C:\Users\VirtualNonsense\.cargo\cargo-generate.toml
 Using ssh-identity from application config: $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
 Favorite git@github.com:VirtualNonsense/rust_bluepill_minimal_template.git not found in config, using it as a git repo url
 Using private key: `%userprofile%\.ssh\id_rsa` for git-ssh checkout
Error:  Git Error: Failed to authenticate SSH session: ; class=Ssh (23)
```

My cargo-generate.toml file consists only of the following lines:

```ini
[defaults]
ssh_identity = "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

I've seen that there seems to be an issue with passphrase protected keys so I made sure mine does not have one. I also tied an ed25519 key but it did not change the result as well.
I feel like I'm missing something obvious and would appreciate some guidance

Comment: When you say you have no issues with `git`, it means something like `git clone git@github.com:VirtualNonsense/rust_bluepill_minimal_template` works?

Comment: Yes exactly. I cloned myself cargo generate in order to find out whats going on but since I'm still a rust novice I'm having a hard time to figure it out.

Comment: I'm stuggling with a similar issue. See [#hakoerber/git-repo-manager/61](https://github.com/hakoerber/git-repo-manager/issues/61). Did you find a resolution?